# How can I debug C in Geany?

Tags: c, linux, geany, geany-plugin

I've googled it, but every result I got said: add a debugger plugin from Plugin manager, but there is not any option for a debugger plugin. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

I use Ubuntu.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/455222/how-to-use-the-geany-debugger

Comment: Some OS repos may not include a single `geany-plugins` package as indicated in the page linked above, but instead provide a separate package for each plugin. For example, if you were running Fedora, you would want to install the package `geany-plugins-debugger`.

Comment: That answer is not working, I've said above that I am net getting debugger option.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu

Comment: [List of Geany plugins](https://plugins.geany.org/). [Install instructions for Geany plugins](https://plugins.geany.org/install.html).

Comment: What version of Ubuntu (e.g. from output of `lsb_release -a`) do you use?

Answer (score -5):

The Geany plugin manager only lists ***already-installed*** plugins. Despite the name, you can't actually install plugins from Plugin Manager, only enable already-installed ones.

To find and install on Ubuntu:

List available Geany plugins (available through the package system):

```
apt-cache search geany | grep geany-plugin
```

Filter for plugins related to bookmarks (as to why not debuggers, see below):

```
apt-cache search geany | grep geany-plugin | grep -i book
```

The result is:

> geany-plugin-numberedbookmarks - numbered bookmarks plugin for Geany

Install it (based on the exact name from above, *"geany-plugin-numberedbookmarks"*):

```
sudo apt-get install geany-plugin-numberedbookmarks
```

After this, the plugin *"Numbered Bookmarks"* is now listed in Plugin Manager.

#### The "Debugger" Geany plugin is not available in later versions of Ubuntu

The [web site list of plugins for Geany](https://plugins.geany.org/debugger.html) has *"[Debugger](http://plugins.geany.org/debugger.html)"*, but it is not available through the package system in [Ubuntu 19.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_19.10_(Eoan_Ermine)). You need [a Ubuntu version](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2020/03/29/using-geany/) [prior to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068430/geany-plugin-debugger-missing-in-ubuntu-18-04). On [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29), the output from `apt-cache search geany` includes *"geany-plugin-debugger – debugger plugin for Geany"*.

Tested with:

- Ubuntu 19.10, 64 bit (but using desktop environment [Cinnamon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon_(desktop_environment)) instead of GNOME) and Geany version 1.35.
- Ubuntu 16.10, 32 bit and Geany version 1.27 (2016-04-17).